# How to make a good looking cake with a mountain like shape?

Tags: baking, cake, professional

Generally speaking, and not specifying any particular recipe, why does my cake have a small dome on top, while the chef's recipe looks like this:

[image]

The dome on top looks like a mountain, with a good looking shape and shiny syrup glaze.

A local chef said that I should add a line of butter on top of the cake batter, so it will help explode in the middle and allow for even cooking.

But I still can't get the mountain shape.

My cake looks good but not as the original:

[image]

Is it an oven problem ?

Comment: Are you using the correct size loaf pan, as specified in the recipe?

Comment: @moscafj no of course. Should I fill the pan to the 3/4 of it so it can go more up ?

Comment: @alim1990 don't lose sight of the important variable of the pan that you are using to recreate a cake recipe.  Size and shape are extremely important if you are looking to achieve the same results.

Comment: @Luciano : I'm wondering if there was something on the Great British Bake Off or similar that would make multiple people want to bake the same type of take

Comment: @Joe maybe, I haven't followed the show for a while.